# Getting view details on onGroupClick which i clicked in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

How to get the view details on click happened. I need to get it in onGroupClick of ExpandableListView, since i having to do multiple functionalities on Expandable GroupView.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What was the result? The onGroupClick() method passes a view parameter. What details do you want about that view?

Comment: Use the above link to start then if you get stuck post a question with the code you are attempting, the desired result, and the current result along with any error messages if they exist.

Comment: Not able to edit the question, i am getting this as response while editing "Your post cannot be submitted at this time due to the volume of spam and abuse originating from your network. ". About the code, i have implemented expandable listview onGroupClickListener, i was struck in here the get the exact view in which the click happen. More details, i have 5 views in parent view, one do the expand and rest does other functionalities. I have to find out the view on which it is clicked. @codeMagic the link you posted didnt helped me.

Comment: About the posting restriction, [See this part of the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/abuse-block). As far as the link not helping you, it is more of a start than what you originally posted. See [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you ask a very broad question and no code showing what you have tried, you will have a lot of trouble finding help here.

Comment: @codeMagic Ok thanks for the link. Did you understood my question from previous comment.

Comment: Somewhat. But as you can see from that method, you already have that view and the position. So you should be able to use that to get started to get the position from the adapter.